# Cache user control with varybyparam in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, caching, outputcache, webusercontrol

I am developing a page where some graphs are showing depending on user. I'm writing graphs code in usercontrol and trying to cache it using varybyparam with userid.I am adding this user control dynamically to my aspx page.

Now my problem is how can I pass userid to user control from aspx page code behind while loading usercontrol as query string parameter. Please help me to solve this.